# Could not retreive data for account https://dev.azure.com/xxxx

Tags: visual-studio, ado

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00k0J.png)In VisualStudio, we get this error when we try to clone an 'Azure DevOps' Repo from 'VisualStudio' 'Clone Repository'.

1. Launch VisualStudio
2. Clone a repository
3. Connect to a Project
4. And the error occurs:
   What we tried so far?
5. We tried deleting the '.identityService' file in the '%localdata%' folder with no luck.
6. Tried readding the 'user' to 'ADO'.